# How to install erlang modules from github?

Tags: module, installation, erlang, jiffy

I am new to Erlang and I need to install [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) on my Mac.

When I `make` / `rebar compile`, jeffy compiles without any errors.  But I cant use it anywhere from shell.

Do I have to copy `.so` files?  How should I install erlang modules generally?  I came from Python world.

Comment: Are you about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236950/add-path-to-erlang-search-path

Comment: Erlang has its release system and a lot of tools that make development, releasing and environment setup easy. More, enough information in the net provided on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start erlang shell with (after compilation):

```
 erl -pa <jiffypath>/ebin/
```