# How do I install a driver in Erlang? (Specifically MySQL-otp driver)

Tags: mysql, erlang, erlang-otp, erl

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp) this driver looks great. I don't know how to install it so that I can use it though. I read somewhere that I should maybe use [rebar?](https://github.com/basho/rebar) I looked at that documentation though and it appears to have the opposite problem. It says how to install it, but not how to use it.

---

**Update**

So it looks like after installing rebar, I can add the lines

```
{deps, [
    {mysql, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp",
                   {tag, "1.3.3"}}}
]}.
```

to my file rebar.config. I don't know what this does though. Do I have to compile or make this file now? Does rebar.config have to be in the same directory as my project? Right not the path to rebar.config is `~/rebar/rebar.config`
Is it all correct to place my project so that it is a sibling to rebar in the file hierarchy?

---

**Update**

I ran `./rebar get-deps` with the rebar folder and got

```
Pulling mysql from {git,"https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp",
                        {tag,"1.3.3"}}
Cloning into 'mysql'...
==> mysql (get-deps)
```

I still don't really know what this means though, and when I try compiling my erlang file I receive the result.

```
c(erlangFile.erl).
{error,non_existing}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download your package, in this case

```
git clone https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp.git
```

Download a tool called [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar)

```
git clone git://github.com/rebar/rebar.git
cd rebar
./bootstrap
```

[Add the following to rebar/rebar.config](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp)

```
{deps, [
    {mysql, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp",
                   {tag, "1.3.3"}}}
]}.
```

Within the rebar/mysql-otp directory run

```
./rebar get-deps
```

Then within the same directory, run

```
./rebar compile
```

This will put a bunch of .beam files and .app file into the ebin/ directory

Next add the ebin/ directory to your path. You can update your $ERL_LIBS environment variable, [run an include command within the erlang console like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896336/how-do-you-install-a-module-in-erlang)

```
1> code:add_pathz("~/rebar/mysql-otp/ebin").
```

or

```
1> code:add_pathz("rebar/mysql-otp/ebin")
```

[And theres a few other ways to add it to your Erlang path.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236950/add-path-to-erlang-search-path)

---

Also, make sure mysql is also installed

Heres a few links with mysql installation instructions that worked for me

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7

[No package msyql-server available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712228/no-package-msyql-server-available)

Answer (score 1):

rebar is a build tool for erlang.Please go through https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Rebar-commands for the commands.
After getting dependency, "rebar compile" is required to compile it.
For using the beam files, you have to give output beam path using [Add Path to Erlang Search Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236950/add-path-to-erlang-search-path)
these methods.
Then you will be able to use it in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think really know what beam files are. The name rings a bell but I'm new enough to Erlang that I don't think I've learned what they are. Would you be able to explain them in this specific context.

And is the Erlang path similar to a PythonPath or ShellPath but this one is just for Erlang?

Thanks again.

Comment: you should first go through basics of erlang before going forward.go through this https://learnyousomeerlang.com/content

Comment: I'm just going to research beam files, because I've already read through several tutorials like that

Comment: I don't think I ever use beam files because I always just run `erl` on the command line and then `c(myerlangfile).` Do I have to use them in this case?