# No package msyql-server available

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, package

I'm trying to set up MySQL on an Amazon Linux instance, I've tried everything (and with the -y option as well):

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-server 
$ sudo yum install mysql56-server 
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

I keep getting the "No package msqql-server available", "No package msyql56-server available", etc...

I've also ran yum clean all, yum update all, etc...

I'm assuming I have to install the RPM, but I don't know what version to install and while there is documentation for CentOS, there is little documentation specifically for Amazon Linux for setting up MySQL.

And these instructions didn't work as I got the error message "No package mysql56-server available" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Answer (score 26):

This worked:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm

sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

Comment: These steps worked like a charm. But I had a hard time because I didn't knew how to get the root password.

`grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log |tail -1`

Comment: @GilbertoTreviño what was the password then?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo please run `grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -1` on your shell, this should give you the password. If I remember correctly, that is a random hash generated each time a new installation is done.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE for 2022:

```
rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
service mysqld start
```

ref:
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4419382481815?input_string=gpg+keys+problem+with+mysql+5.7