# I am getting error like "no Package mysql-server available" while installing mysql-server on ec2 linux instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

```
sudo yum install MySQL-server
```

this is the error which I am getting
[image]

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712228/no-package-msyql-server-available

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install wget
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm
md5sum mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql57-community-release-el7-9.noarch.rpm

yum install mysql-server
```